# Visual Studio 2017 toolbar icon missing after update to 15.1.26403.00

Tags: visual-studio

VS 2017 after update to 15.1.26403.00

all toolbar/soluction window  icon missing

I try

1."tools->setting->reset all setting "

2. del ImageLibrary.cache in
   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_f16c2fde\ImageLibrary

3.install hot fix for VS 2015

FIX: Images are missing in Visual Studio 2015
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3095681/fix-images-are-missing-in-visual-studio-2015

is not fix it.

please help tks.

[VS 2017 toolbar icon missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i17Sb.png)

Answer (score 5):

1. From start menu, right click Visual Studio 2017 to open the file location.
2. From the location, right click Visual Studio 2017, go to properties to change the icon.
3. Try to open vs2017, and see what happend in taskbar.

You can change it back to default icon

Answer (score 0):

Install latest update on Visual studio 2017. As of today 15.4.4

or 
follow these instructions.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/94502/visual-studio-2017-153-toolbar-icons-are-missing.html